# Visual C++ Library for windows programing

Tags: c++, windows

which library is best for windows programing today in Visual C++, which one is most used today,   etc
ATL, MFC, WTL and others..  and how many exist ?

Thanks

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: ok deleted, but web is full of tutorials and choosing best is hard

Comment: I say use the `Qt` framework if you are doing c++ development. Otherwise use `c#` on the .net platform.

Comment: Please clarify "best".Do you need ease of Use?  Do you need minimal features?  Maximum Features?  Cross platform?  Embedded systems? Support multiple programming languages?  Support multiple languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start the answer "from the back": there are **many** libraries for doing UI on Windows :)

Having said that I do have a few recommendations for you:

1. If you want to do cross-platform UI development then I suggest you look into `Qt` framework
2. If your goal is to do modern Universal Windows Apps - look no further than the UWP technology
3. For creating COM components I would recommend ATL
4. If you choose MFC you will probably get outdated in the near future (definitely within the 10 years time frame)

But ultimately the technology stack you chose greatly depends on your language of choice and your expertise as a software engineer

Comment: What about wxWidgets and XWindows?

Comment: They fall under "there are **many** libraries" statement at the beginning of my answer. I couldn't possibly have listed all the options so just provided my personal recommendations. I'm sure there are other opinions on this out there (which is why this particular question is off-topic) and my answer was in no way meant to be undisputed or ultimately complete